# Grimm brothers talking to ghosts?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I am trying to find a story in which knowledge of historical sound changes is important for talking to ghosts.

I am pretty sure one of the Grimm brothers was involved (aside from documenting fairy tales, they are well known for their work in historical Germanic linguistics).

A ghost might have been summoned specifically to analyze its dialect, but I think it was more an issue of knowing historical sound laws ahead of time so as to be able to identify the era a ghost came from and deduce how to talk to it.

Not sure if it was actually a published story, or just a Tumblr post or something, but I recall one specific scene of talking to a ghost and discussing the correspondences between the ghosts language and that of the modern necromancers who found it.